# jQuery Canvas Hover Shape changes properties

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, hover, mouseover

Ok, I have looked through endless tutorials for this specific end goal I want to accomplish with jQuery canvas. I have drawn a map using the canvas element in html5 and jQuery. What I am trying to accomplish is when the mouse hovers over a specific shape (not a rectangle nor circle), but a complex polygonal shape, the shape changes color as well as have text to appear.

I also would want a small dialog box to pop up for this specific shape. I do not want the whole canvas to be the target of the hovering function, just a certain piece of it.

Think of a college campus map, with all of the separate buildings placed next to each other. If I hover over a specific building, the color of the building would change and tell me the name of the building (i.e. Science Bldg.). I do not want the color of the text to be the same color as the building that is being hovered over.

I don't know if this can be accomplished by defining multiple paths through variables and functions or multiple canvases on top of each other. I hope that I have specified enough of what I want to accomplish. If anyone can help me, I would hope that they can lead me to the right direction and/or post an example like via jsfiddle.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define a Path for each building and then you can hit-test those paths to see if the mouse is hovering inside one of the buildings in your map.

Here's a narrative outline of how to accomplish your task:

- Plot the x/y coordinate points of each building.  One way you can get the xy coordinates is opening your map in Paint (or similar program) that gives you mouse coordinates.
- Use context.drawImage to draw your map on the canvas.
- Listen for mousemove events (canvas.onmousemove)
- In the mousemove handler, hit-test each building path (a) define a path with beginPath+moveTo+lineTo (b) hit test with context.isPointInPath.
- If you get a hit then use context.fillStyle to set a color for your text then draw your text label on the canvas context.fillText("This is the auditorium",150,35)